# How do you get Monodevelop back to using English for its language

Tags: monodevelop

I have no idea how it happened,  but suddenly when I launch Monodevelop,  the menus appear in a language other than English.  I have tried reinstalling the application as well as manually removing artifacts in other directories under Library.   No luck.  After a reinstall,  it loads in another language still.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the Language under the options/preferences dialog.

For me the shortcut keystroke is 'command + comma'
Or it is the third menu entry under MonoDevelop menu.

Select the first child entry in the left tree view.  "Visual Style"
On the right there are three tabs across the top.  Select the first.  "General"

The "User Interface Language" setting is the second combo box on that screen.

Change that and click OK at the bottom of the screen.  Should be on the right.

Restart MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please open a bug on https://bugzilla.xamarin.com, including the Version Info from MD's about dialog, and attach your preferences file "~/Library/Preferences/MonoDevelop-2.8/MonoDevelopProperties.xml"?