# How to change C# compiler output language in MonoDevelop (Unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing a game in Unity3D and I use C# as scripting language. My MonoDevelop is in English but the output is in Italian (only the output...). I want the output in English. What can I do?

Comment: Is this a fix for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491457/how-do-you-get-monodevelop-back-to-using-english-for-its-language

Comment: No because the environment is already in English. I want the compiler output to be in English.